# Parsing nested templates

Tags: python

The code below will transform templates (given as chars for the test) marked as such by parenthesis (the template delimiters) to their expanded form. Each template is handled by a call to a separate function (`handle()` in the code) and the transformation can happen only once. There can be nested templates and the parser should detect that. There are cases where the handler can't expand unknown templates and will return the template untouched in its delimiters (for further processing at later time when handler is updated.)

The code posted below works for the most part. The only test case it doesn't pass is an input with two nested unknown templates.

I've resorted to some kludges to make this work and I wonder if there is not something better (a Python library maybe?). In particular, the code needs to concatenate the result in reverse order (stack based) and mark items already processed with different operator. Finally, I had to use `join()` for the result as the parser splits between same levels of parenthesis.

**UPDATE**

More use cases to clarify how to use the code.

```
def parse(tokens):
    operStack = list()
    exprStack = list()

    for c in tokens:
        if c.isalpha():
            exprStack.append(c)
            operStack.append("+")

        elif c == '(':
            operStack.append(c)

        elif c == ")":
            concat = ""
            while operStack[-1] != '(':
                operator = operStack.pop()
                c = exprStack.pop()
                if operator == "+":
                    c = handle(c)
                concat = c + concat  # reverse

            operStack.pop()  # discard '('

            exprStack.append(concat)
            operStack.append("-")  # mark item

        else:
            raise RuntimeError()  # should never come here.

    return "".join(exprStack)


def handle(letter):
    letters = dict (a="Apple", b="Banana", c="Car", d="Dog", e="Elephant")

    try:
        word = letters[letter]  # found a match, substitute letter for word
        return " %s " % word
    except KeyError:
        return "(%s)" % letter  # unhandled case, return the letter


def check(actual, expected):
    print("SUCCESS" if actual == expected else "FAILED: got '%s', expected '%s'" % (actual, expected))    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check(parse("(a)"), " Apple ")  # simple template
    check(parse("(a)(b)"), " Apple  Banana ")  # two templates
    check(parse("(a(b(c)))"), " Apple  Banana  Car ")  # nested template
    check(parse("(a(b(c(f))))"), " Apple  Banana  Car (f)")  # one missing nested template
    check(parse("(a)(b(c(d(f(g)))(e)))"), " Apple  Banana  Car  Dog (f(g)) Elephant ")  # two missing nested template
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @melpomene I hesitated about using it, but I am more concerned about the choice of algorithm (ast) to solve this problem than the quality of the code. Should I still use codereview if I am doubting the algorithm?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. What does "expand a macro" mean? What is your expected output? As far as I can tell, inner parentheses have no effect on the output of your code, which makes it very hard to understand what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Blckknght Added more use cases and update explanation. Hopefully this will provide answers to the questions you were asking for.

Comment: I still don't really understand what the parentheses mean in your inputs. As far as I can tell, you should be able to just delete them all, and translate the other characters. Should there be a difference between `(a(b(c)))` and `(a)(b)(c)` or `(a(b)(c))`? Your current code doesn't seem to make one.

Comment: I am afraid it's not that simple. Not wanting to post the whole handler, I simplified it to the point where you are making a valid point. However, there are two things that need to happen: the handler can use internal templates in their modified forms (a would use b & c). The other thing is that when the template is not handled it needs to go back into parens. That's the part that has given me trouble. If I remove the parens, I lose the hierarchy. If I keep the parens, then the parser needs to understand the recursive match or ( and ).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using a PEG based parser (Parsing expression grammar) which gave me the opportunity to learn the difference between its more precise behavior and the Context free grammar I have learned during my compiler class.